# Keycloak 18.0.0 Cluster on K8S ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED login page

Tags: keycloak, quarkus

Finally i managed to make my Keycloak 18.0.0 K8S Cluster run.

Still, once i login to the keycloak the https://10.19.76.82/admin/master/console/ page is not loading and i get this error:

```
 check3pCookiesSupported @ https://10.19.76.82/js/keycloak.js?version=2yhtw:1973
T @ https://10.19.76.82/js/keycloak.js?version=2yhtw:16
(anonymous) @ https://10.19.76.82/js/keycloak.js?version=2yhtw:16
a @ https://10.19.76.82/js/keycloak.js?version=2yhtw:16
(anonymous) @ https://10.19.76.82/js/keycloak.js?version=2yhtw:16
z @ https://10.19.76.82/js/keycloak.js?version=2yhtw:16
A @ https://10.19.76.82/js/keycloak.js?version=2yhtw:16
w @ https://10.19.76.82/js/keycloak.js?version=2yhtw:16
(anonymous) @ https://10.19.76.82/js/keycloak.js?version=2yhtw:16
setSuccess @ https://10.19.76.82/js/keycloak.js?version=2yhtw:1822
req.onreadystatechange @ https://10.19.76.82/js/keycloak.js?version=2yhtw:1555
```

(failed)net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Assistance will be much appreciated, Thanks!!!!

Here are my config files:

> show-config:
>
> ```
>  kc.cache =  ispn (PersistedConfigSource)
>  kc.cache-config-file =  cache-ispn-jdbc-ping.xml (PersistedConfigSource)
>  kc.config.args =  show-config (SysPropConfigSource)
>  kc.db =  mysql (PropertiesConfigSource[source=file:/opt/keycloak/bin/../conf/keycloak.conf])
>  kc.db-password =  ******* (PropertiesConfigSource[source=file:/opt/keycloak/bin/../conf/keycloak.conf])
>  kc.db-url =  jdbc:mysql://10.16.19.105/dbkeycloak (PropertiesConfigSource[source=file:/opt/keycloak/bin/../conf/keycloak.conf])
>  kc.db-username =  keycloak_service (PropertiesConfigSource[source=file:/opt/keycloak/bin/../conf/keycloak.conf])
>  kc.health-enabled =  false (PersistedConfigSource)
>  kc.home.dir =  /opt/keycloak/bin/../ (SysPropConfigSource)
>  kc.http-enabled =  false (PropertiesConfigSource[source=jar:file:///opt/keycloak/lib/lib/main/org.keycloak.keycloak-quarkus-server-18.0.0.jar!/META-INF/keycloak.conf])
>  kc.http-relative-path =  / (PersistedConfigSource)
>  kc.log-console-output =  default (PropertiesConfigSource[source=jar:file:///opt/keycloak/lib/lib/main/org.keycloak.keycloak-quarkus-server-18.0.0.jar!/META-INF/keycloak.conf])
>  kc.log-file =  /opt/keycloak/bin/../data/log/keycloak.log (PropertiesConfigSource[source=jar:file:///opt/keycloak/lib/lib/main/org.keycloak.keycloak-quarkus-server-18.0.0.jar!/META-INF/keycloak.conf])
>  kc.metrics-enabled =  true (PersistedConfigSource)
>  kc.provider.file.remote-user-storage-provider-jar-with-dependencies.jar.last-modified = 1651771298000 (PersistedConfigSource)
>  kc.quarkus-properties-enabled =  false (PersistedConfigSource)
>  kc.show.config =  none (SysPropConfigSource)
>  kc.version =  18.0.0 (SysPropConfigSource)
> ```
>
> keycloak.conf:
>
> ```
> db=mysql
> db-username=keycloak_service
> db-password=AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
> db-url=jdbc:mysql://10.11.11.11/dbkeycloak
> metrics-enabled=true
> hostname=keycloak.lalala.com
> ```

> keycloak-deployment.yml:
>
> ```
> apiVersion: apps/v1
> kind: Deployment
> metadata:
>   name: keycloak
>   namespace: keycloak
>   labels:
>     app: keycloak
> spec:
>   replicas: 3
>   selector:
>     matchLabels:
>       app: keycloak
>   template:
>     metadata:
>       labels:
>         app: keycloak
>     spec:
>       containers:
>         - name: keycloak
>           image: lalala/keycloak:11111
>           args: ["start"]
>           env:
>            - name: KEYCLOAK_ADMIN
>              value: "admin"
>            - name: KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD
>              value: "admin"
>            - name: PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING
>              value: "true"
>            - name: JGROUPS_DISCOVERY_PROTOCOL
>              value: dns.DNS_PING
>            - name: JGROUPS_DISCOVERY_PROPERTIES
>              value: "dns_query=keycloak"
>            - name: CACHE_OWNERS_COUNT
>              value: "2"
>            - name: CACHE_OWNERS_AUTH_SESSIONS_COUNT
>              value: "2"
>            - name: KC_METRICS_ENABLED
>              value: "true" 
>            ##### DB Variables #########
>            ##
>            - name: KC_DB_USERNAME
>              value: keycloak_service
>            - name: KC_DB_PASSWORD
>              value: "keycloakpass"
>            - name: KC_DB_URL_HOST
>              value: "10.16.19.105"
>            - name: KC_DB_URL_DATABASE
>              value: dbkeycloak
>            - name: KC_DB
>              value: mysql
>            ##### HTTPS Variables #########
>            ##
>            - name: KC_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_FILE
>              value: /opt/keycloak/certs/taptica.com.crt
>            - name: KC_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_KEY_FILE
>              value: /opt/keycloak/certs/taptica.com.key    
>            - name: KC_HOSTNAME
>              value: keycloak.taptica.com
>            - name: KC_PROXY
>              value: reencrypt
>            - name: KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS
>              value: "false" 
>           ports:
>             - name: jgroups
>               containerPort: 7600
>             - name: http
>               containerPort: 8080
>             - name: https
>               containerPort: 8443
>       imagePullSecrets:
>       - name: lalala-registry-dockerhub
> ```

UPDATE:

The config above is now updated and it is working

Thanks alot!

Comment: Hey. I am not quite sure what config is really applied right now. Could you please clarify: Is the keycloak.conf really completely commented out? So you're using the values from `env` in your spec? If so, there is no `PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true` effect, you'd have to set `KC_PROXY=reencrypt`. Did not make this an answer yet bc. it's unclear what config you set, bc the one from `keycloak.conf` would be applied and its another error if so. But your `show-config` output does not show that the right proxy mode is applied, so maybe thats the issue.

Comment: To clarify: When you can reach the welcome page (path `/`) but on trying to reach the login page get a blank page, its almost always a proxy setup issue.  May also be that my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72070158/cannot-access-keycloak-admin-pannel-after-connect-to-postgresql-in-docker/72071058#72071058 might help you.

Comment: Thanks Dominik! it works now - i updated the configuration on the main post above. Can you tell me why i must keep the db, db-username, db-password and db-url on the keycloak.conf file even that i added them as ENV variables ? when i remark then on the conf file it is not working. Thanks again